# Creating multipart Annotations using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, annotation

I am currently working with the geometries of Annotations inside a bigger Python script (ArcGIS Pro Version 3.1.0). The Annotations I'm working with come from Point, Polyline and Polygon Feature Classes and have all kinds of shapes. See the following examples.

Example 1 - Converted from a Polygon FC with "River Placement" Option (multipart):

[image]

Example 2 - Converted from a Polyline FC with "River Placement" Option (singlepart):

[image]

Example 3 - Same as Example 2 but a multi line Annotation (singlepart):

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that I don't understand if and how I can control whether an Annotation Geometry will be single- or multipart. Ultimately, I want all of the Anno Geometries to be multipart and have one geometry part per word.

If there is not any option or combination of values in the Label Class that will produce the desired result (as shown in Example 1), is it possible to extract something similar from the CIM representation of the Annotation FC?

I was reading about the CIMTextGraphic Class and that it has a shape but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Are you "converting" from ArcPro Maplex labeling layers?

Comment: @danak Yes, i am using the Maplex Label Engine.